# value too long for type character varying(200) in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-models

I am using the django model for my project When I hit my query to insert the row.I am getting an error

Query:

```
 INSERT INTO "intelligence_centre_organicsearchresults" 
 ("keyword", "location", "position", "page_no", "headline", "url", "exerpt", "query_url", "content_updated_date", "created_on", "modified_on", "downloaded") 
 VALUES 
 (E'abilify', NULL, 8, 1, E'NAMI | Abilify (aripiprazole)', E'/url?q=http://www.nami.org/Template.cfm?Section=About_Medications&template=/ContentManagement/ContentDisplay.cfm&ContentID=8133&sa=U&ei=-v5VT7HkHMTsrAf5wqCLBw&ved=0CEEQFjAH&usg=AFQjCNG7-G-LSrWE65DeZuDmy2Uvi71HTg', E'What is the most important information I should know about Abilify®? Relapse is very common in schizophrenia and the most frequent cause is that patients stop ...www.nami.org/Template.cfm?Section=About_Medications... - Cached - Similar', NULL, NULL, E'2012-03-06 06:11:37.606388', E'2012-03-06 06:11:37.606449', true)
```

Error:

```
   ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(200)
```

My schema field sizes are also extended for this problem:

```
  ALTER TABLE intelligence_centre_adwordsearchresults
ALTER COLUMN landing_page_url TYPE character varying(1000)
```

likewise I had extended the size for all fields.

i have attached my table description as screen shot.

[image]

Please suggest me to solve this error?

Comment: The next time please post table definitions as `CREATE TABLE` statements. Or at least as a formatted text, but not as a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the table names first. Your solution is okay if you see the table names.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error inserting into `intelligence_centre_ORGANICsearchresults`, but you've altered the columns on `intelligence_centre_ADWORDsearchresult`s. I think you need to alter the columns on `intelligence_centre_ORGANICsearchresults`.